selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot deserialize the result value received from Runtime.callFunctionOn when trying to get page sournce
I've started to get the error below when trying to get the page source, using selenium.
My java code looks like this:
private String getPageContentRaw(String URL, Long waitDelay, Long waitForPageLoadPollInterval) throws Exception {
    try {
        this.driver.get(URL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        this.driver.get(URL);
    }
     
    waitForPageToLoad(waitDelay, waitForPageLoadPollInterval);

    return this.driver.getPageSource();
}

The error is thrown when calling:

this.driver.getPageSource();

Any idea what could cause it?
Thanks
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot deserialize the result value received from Runtime.callFunctionOn
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.122)
Build info: version: '4.16.1', revision: '9b4c83354e'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.8.5-201.fc39.x86_64', java.version: '21.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [80030c19b0e32fb50aaa2dbecd4b0d2d, getPageSource {}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 123.0.6312.122, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 123.0.6312.122 (31f8248cdd9...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:9999}, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: any, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:9999/devtool..., se:cdpVersion: 123.0.6312.122, setWindowRect: false, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 80030c19b0e32fb50aaa2dbecd4b0d2d
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:52)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:191)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:200)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:175)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:523)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:596)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getPageSource(RemoteWebDriver.java:386)
        at 


I've just got the same "WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot deserialize the result value received from Runtime.callFunctionOn"
In my case it was selenium+python3 and .text method. I got baffled first because it happened not every time but then I saw that the part of the page changes at the moment when the error appear.
Try to proceed the exception as if it were StaleElementException. I have met such behavior of Selenium long before now ('No node with given id found').
Instead of <return this.driver.getPageSource();>
try
loop
    try
        some_var = this.driver.getPageSource();
    catch exception
        retry
    break loop
return some_var

Sorry I'm not familiar with javascript.
